# Disable cachebusting string Ember-CLI production build

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I need to have images in my Ember-CLI application for which I change the path dynamically, i.e.  `<img src="my_dynamic_path">`.

However, because Ember adds a cachebusting string to all the images, I can't do this.

Is there any way to disable the cachebusting string, or some function that finds a URL of a cachebusted image-name, or a folder which is unaffected by this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things that you can do, ember-cli uses [broccoli-asset-rev](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev) to fingerprint files.

You can either disable fingerprinting:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  fingerprint: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

You can choose to exclude certain directories/files:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  fingerprint: {
    exclude: ['my/ignored/directory']
  }
});
```

For more information regarding fingerprinting check out [asset compilation](http://www.ember-cli.com/asset-compilation/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls) in the [docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/).